# Which way you prefer to send arguments?

Tags: c++, c, programming-languages

Suppose you have a function:

```
void fun(int *a, int *b);
```

Which way you would prefer to send the arguments?

(1.)

```
int x, y;
fun(&x, &y);
```

(2.)

```
int *x, *y;
fun(x, y);
```

What are the problems with other way or both are same and their behavior will also be the same?

Comment: The two don't have remotely the same semantics- you are passing uninitialized pointers in the second, but a pointer to a valid int in the first. Are you in C++ or C, because the answer is going to be very different.

Comment: @DeadMG how's that going to be "very" different? As in operator overloading? (the example here is `int`) Or something else?

Comment: @kizzx2: Because in C++, you would use references for some situations and pointers for others.

Comment: @DeadMG: **If** a function takes pointers, you are not going to force reference down it? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you use the former if you want the variables on the stack, and the latter if you allocate memory for them on the heap. The stack is typically faster, whereas the heap is typically bigger. So in general, you use the first pattern quite often, and only use the latter when dealing with giant arrays or very large objects.

Answer (score 2):

In C++ we usually pass objects as references. This is a benefit since there is less worry about NULL pointers.

In your second example code, you are passing two uninitialized `int *` which will cause undefined behavior. You will never be able to assign to `*x` or `*y` (technically you can, but it's UB and your program might crash). Prefer the first example code, since you are pointing to actual objects.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is *totally irrelevant*. The behaviors are the same. Just use what's convenient and common sense. If some pointers are already around, use them. If it's short and no variables store the address, just prefix `&`, etc. It's not a big deal.

Comment: I downvoted, because if you read the OP, he clearly does not exhibit the same behaviour each way- that is, in the first, fun is passed a pointer to two existing ints, whereas in the second, fun is passed a pair of uninitialized pointers.

Comment: @DeadMG Maybe. I thought he was just not repeating the obvious but who knows.

Answer (score 0):

I usually prefer references for output parameters. The second option of yours has the possibilty to pass a null-pointer which the function might want to process in a special way. Also the second is dangerous, because you pass dangling pointers

Comment: @awoodland: yeah, which is what I meant by "dangling" :)

Comment: But it has the disadvantage, that you cannot see that they are output arguments while "&" clearly gives some hint. Thats why people prefer pointers. I think also the authors of the Google C++ Guidelines had this in mind.

Comment: You can tell if references are input or output parameters very concisely by the keyword const.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to agree with Google's c++ style guideline, where they request that input parameters be const references (const &), and output parameters are pointers.

```
void Foo(const string &in, string *out)
```

This gives the user an immediate pattern queue that the parameter *in* (above) is an input parameter, and *out* is an output parameter.

Comment: The OP's question asks how to create the arguments required in order to call the function, not how to write the function itself.

Answer (score -2):

Either way functionality is same. There is no change in the behavior.

With the second option, if x and y not initialized properly, there is a scope for segmentation fault.